# Reading and writing files concurrently

Tags: php, linux, file, ubuntu, concurrency

On Linux, if one script is reading a (big) file and another is trying to write into the same file, will the both operations succeed so that the first script reads non-corrupted data (because of inodes)? (Suppose I'm using `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents`)

Comment: The answer will probably be "it depends". It depends on which functions you use for file access. Do you have some particular in mind?

Comment: @MaxK file_get_contents and file_put_contents

Comment: @DesmondHume: Those are exactly the problematic few "some functions" that I mention in my last paragraph below. These will use filemapping on some architectures, and won't on others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "most correct" answer is: **No**.

Although the small print is a bit more elaborate: Both operations will succeed, and you will never see *corrupted* data in the strictest sense of the wording. However, the data you see may not be consistent. That means if you write "ABC" then writing "AB" may be realized before someone is reading (and the last bit of data will be whatever was in the file before), but "ABC" will never be corrupted into "pnt" or "CDQ".
Further, if two processes are concurrently writing, it is possible that only part of one write is realized before the other one is realized. For example, writing "ABCDEF" and "123456" concurrently *might* result in "A2C4E6" being stored in the buffer cache, and subsequently on disk. It *might* also result in "ABCDEF" or in "123456". A third process reading concurrently might pick up any possible combination.

Reads and writes in general are not guaranteed to be atomic. The `readv` and `writev` syscalls are exceptional insofar as they are *guaranteed* to be atomic (on files, at least). This is not what "normal" writes use, however.

Further, library-level caching usually takes place, so in addition to reads and writes not necessarily being atomic in the buffer cache, two processes concurrently reading and writing may have very different ideas of what a file's contents is.

Appending to a file (non-concurrently) and concurrently reading is generally "safe". Not all data might be visible when you read, but whatever you write will end up exactly the way you wrote it.

Note that *some* PHP functions will use filemapping on *some* architectures, which further complicates matters.

**In reply to the edit:** `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` are exactly some of the previously mentioned functions that will use memory mapping on some architectures.
It is not specified on which architectures exactly, but Linux is a rather safe bet.
Now the trouble with memory mapping is that two processes concurrently accessing a file are effectively concurrently accessing the same physical memory. Which means that reads and writes are, again, **not** atomic without explicit synchronization.

Also, you have no *formal* guarantee (although the implementation *practically* guarantees it, since Linux has an unified virtual memory system) that the in-memory view corresponds to the externally observable on-disk representation unless `msync` has been called. Which means that in theory (though not in practice) a different process using normal reads and writes (not using memory mapping) might see something completely different.